# running Scrapy on terminal server

Tags: python, server, scrapy, web-crawler, client

i wanna crawling on server side but my python it isnt so good...

my source is works so well, if i running it on mylaptop terminal, but it was going wrong when running it on server terminal

here my source code

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from thehack.items import NowItem
import time

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "nowhere"
    allowed_domains = ["n0where.net"]
    start_urls = ["https://n0where.net/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for article in response.css('.loop-panel'):
            item = NowItem()
            item['title'] = article.css('.article-title::text').extract_first()
            item['link'] = article.css('.loop-panel>a::attr(href)').extract_first()
            item['body'] ='' .join(article.css('.excerpt p::text').extract()).strip()
            #date ga kepake
            #item['date'] = article.css('[itemprop="datePublished"]::attr(content)').extract_first()
            yield item
            time.sleep(5)
```

the wrong line said

```
ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://n0where.net/>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 824, in runUntilCurrent
    call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/task.py", line 638, in _tick
    taskObj._oneWorkUnit()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/task.py", line 484, in _oneWorkUnit
    result = next(self._iterator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 57, in <genexpr>
    work = (callable(elem, *args, **named) for elem in iterable)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 96, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/contrib/spidermiddleware/offsite.py", line 26, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/contrib/spidermiddleware/referer.py", line 22, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/contrib/spidermiddleware/urllength.py", line 33, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/contrib/spidermiddleware/depth.py", line 50, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/home/admin/nowhere/thehack/spiders/thehack_spider.py", line 14, in parse
    item['title'] = article.css('.article-title::text').extract_first()
exceptions.AttributeError: 'SelectorList' object has no attribute 'extract_first'
```

does anybody know how to fix it mate?
thanks a lot before :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your scrapy version is out of date. `scrapy.Selector` method `.extract_first()` was only added in scrapy 1.1, so you want to upgrade the scrapy package on your server.

Comment: mate i try to _sudo pip install --upgrade scrapy_

and got result
** Rolling back uninstall of lxml
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-WJUVpy/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-yn9nU9-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-WJUVpy/lxml/**
can you give me another suggestion mate?

Comment: @jethow what's the distro your server is running on? On ubuntu you can just try `apt install python-scrapy`, version 1.1 should be in ubuntu repos.

Comment: i am using ubuntu 14.04.4 mate, i've try it...
its says _E: Unable to locate package Scrapy_